# Applying Matrix row operation to both sides of a matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A$, $B$, $X$ be matrices of the same order such that $X = AB$.

When applying an elementary row operation to the matrix equation of $X = AB$, then the elementary row operation is applied to $X$ on the left side and only to $A$ on the right side. Why is the elementary row operation in above scenario not applied to the matrix given by the product $AB$ but only to the first matrix $A$ when applying it to left side?

My understanding is that if two matrices $X$ and $Y$ are equal i.e. $X = Y$, then in order to maintain equality we must apply the same elementary row operation to $X$ and $Y$. In the question being posted $Y$ is like $AB$, and it follows that the row operation must apply to the product $AB$ rather than just $A$.

An example is as given below.

[image: Row operation to matrix equation]

Comment: See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix).

Comment: @DavidMitra, thanks. I need to understand the concepts at the link you gave.

Comment: Let $E$ be the **e**lementary matrix which applies the stated row operation.  Here, you have $X=AB$ and you are correct that we should have $EX = E(AB)$, that the row operation would apply to $AB$ collectively.  Here is the punchline however... *matrix multiplication is associative*!  $E(AB)$ is also equal to $(EA)B$.  So, it doesn't matter whether we had our row operation affect the product $AB$ or if we had it affect only $A$.  The overall result is the same!